# Why does my git log fail when using a shell variable for the branch name?

Tags: git, bash, shell

I'm trying to see the difference between two tags, when I hard code my tag names in, it works fine. When I use the tags as shell variables, I get this error.

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'version-02.06.13.115..version-2.06.13.114': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

## This one works well

```
git log version-02.06.13.115..version-02.06.13.114 --oneline
```

## This one gives me an error

```
git log "${currentBranchTag}".."${currentAPI}" --oneline
```

Comment: Because you have a typo: `currentAPI` should be `version-02.06.13.114` and not `version-2.06.13.114` (mind the `0` in front of the `2`).

Comment: sorry, gniourf_gniourf, I wasn't trying to steal your answer - I happened to type mine at the same time you did. Can't delete mine now, complains I already deleted 5 today...

Comment: @Bushmills: no problem... this question should be closed anyways (it's not going to be useful to anyone, and appears to be caused by a simple typographical error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2` should be `02` in `version-2.06.13.114`